# Parse.com Querying nearby items and sorting with time not distance

Tags: android, parse-platform, geolocation

We are making a location based Android chat app using Parse.com, I have saved my chats with location in "Chats" Parse Class. We want chats around given location to be displayed in our app, and they must be in Descending order of "createdTime"(Latest First) .For Querying I am using the following code.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Chat");
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
    query.whereWithinKilometers("location", location, distance);
    query.setLimit(10);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> items, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                // Display Results
            }
        }
```

Retrieved list is not as desired and Parse considers distance for sorting and messes up the list. Is there a way to disable sorting with distance when using "wherewithinkilometers"?

For example, I have

```
chat | location | time
text8| 15,74    | 11.30
text7| 15,74    | 11.25
text6| 15,74    | 11.20
text5| 15,74    | 11.15
text4| 15,74    | 11.10
text3| 15,74    | 11.05
text2| 15,74    | 11.02
text1| 15,74    | 11.00
.......................
```

Retrieved List is

```
chat | location | time
text4| 15,74    | 11.10
text3| 15,74    | 11.05
text1| 15,74    | 11.00
......................
```

If I retrieve all chats with tag "createdAt" and then use only the ones which are within the distance then it works for me. But that wont be the best solution for implementing paging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");`  and sort result of query manually.

From Parse [Android docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#geo)

> Note that if an additional orderByAscending()/orderByDescending() constraint is applied, it will take precedence over the distance ordering.

Update:

I use `Parse-1.8.0.jar`, I did 2 queries with `Asc` and `Desc` sort order, everything works as expected see logs bellow:

```
Ascending by CreateAt
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:15:35 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[10.000000,10.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:15:49 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[20.000000,20.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:15:56 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[15.000000,15.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:09 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[13.000000,13.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:18 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[22.000000,22.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:29 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[0.000000,1.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:34 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[1.000000,0.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:40 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[3.000000,3.000000]
Descending by CreateAt
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:40 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[3.000000,3.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:34 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[1.000000,0.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:29 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[0.000000,1.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:18 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[22.000000,22.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:16:09 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[13.000000,13.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:15:56 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[15.000000,15.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:15:49 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[20.000000,20.000000]
CreateAt: Fri Dec 26 17:15:35 EET 2014, location: ParseGeoPoint[10.000000,10.000000]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want precedence to be taken over by orderByDescending constraint and dont want distance to play any role. I mean get all chats in the area and show them with respect to time. Is that possible? I tried various combinations but it didnt work... :( 
I tried your solution and If I have more than 10 chats(queried chats) within an area then retrieved chats are not the latest ones... I get older chats which are closer to the given location.

Comment: Still not working out for me. I have many Chats with same location, can that be a problem? You have used the same code as mine to get those results? I think its possible to get desired output with parse cloud code, can you help me out with that? I am getting errors with that too...

Comment: @engico why do you sort by `createAt` and refer to text later? why not to sort by text, if you expect it order in some way?

Comment: @engico looks like you need to share your project or maybe sample from it to be able to get some help, because I implemented you requirements at my test project and everything works as expected.